# PIN tool unknown ABI error

Tags: c++, instrumentation

I installed the latest version of PIN from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pintool-downloads). And I modified the created a file to trace calls to gets() using a copy of malloctrace.cpp. However, while compiling, I get an error:

> In file included from ./include/pin/pin.H:41:0,  from
>
> tools/ManualExamples/inputtrace.cpp:32:
>
> ./include/pin/compiler_version_check2.H:83:3: error: #error "Unknown
>
> target  architecture"  # error "Unknown target architecture"    ^
>
> ./include/pin/compiler_version_check2.H:98:2: error: #error "internal
>
> error pin compiler configuration not available "  #error "internal
>
> error pin compiler configuration not available "   ^
>
> ./include/pin/compiler_version_check2.H:102:2: error: #error The C++
>
> ABI of your compiler does not match the ABI of the pin kit.  #error
>
> The C++ ABI of your compiler does not match the ABI of the pin kit.
>
> ^ ./include/pin/compiler_version_check2.H:122:2: error: #error Kit has
>
> unknown compiler ABI  #error Kit has unknown compiler ABI   ^ In file
>
> included from ./include/pin/level_base.PLH:66:0,
>
> from ./include/pin/pin.H:43,
>
> from tools/ManualExamples/inputtrace.cpp:32:
>
> ./include/pin/foundation.PLH:25:28: fatal error: types_marker.TLH: No
>
> such file or directory  #include "types_marker.TLH"
>
> ^
>
> compilation terminated.

I did make sure that the version of PIN I installed was the latest. But the problem persists.
Can someone help me in this regard?

Update: I am using a linux machine x86-64 and the compiler is gcc version 4.8.4

Comment: Can you show us your modifications?

Comment: I don't think the problem lies in the code. The line 32 mentioned corresponds to the line #include "pin.H".
Anyway, [here](http://pastebin.com/E7pT6mnZ) it is

Comment: Jayakrishna Menon, what is your target? (`uname -a`) What is your target OS and CPU and compiler version, is it x86/x86_64 or not, gcc or not?

Comment: oh sorry, forgot to mention that.

linux mint, x86_64, gcc version 4.8.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this as an answer since, I do not have the required reputation to make a comment.

Unless you tell us the exact parameters you used for running `make`, I am afraid a clear and direct answer to your question will not be possible.

This might be a total stab in the dark. But, I ran into a similar problem recently, like you have specified above. I am using an x86_64 Linux system and I was trying to cross-compile my PinTool for ia-32 architecture.

If you do not have 32-bit shared libraries in your system, or if you get the `TARGET` parameter in `make` wrong, it would result in

```
Unknown target architecture
```

For me running the below command, made it build successfully. Use the following to build for ia32 architecture.

```
make TARGET=ia32
```